# How to detect "tab keypress" when focus is at a button using JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I'm just wondering if any of you done an onkeypress on a button.

**my button is like this:**

```
asp:Button ID="btnClear" runat="server" Text="Clear" onkeypress="return goToFirst();"/>
```

**the javascript:**

```
function goToFirst(evt) {
    var e = event || evt; // for trans-browser compatibility
    var charCode = e.which || e.keyCode;

    alert(charCode);
    if (charCode = 9 ) {
        document.getElementById('txtFirstName').focus();
        document.getElementById('txtFirstName').select();
    }

    return false;
```

My goal is to detect the tab keypress on a button and set the focus on the specified textbox when tab is pressed.

The problem is that the onkeypress event does not fire when tab key is pressed. other keys like numbers and letters fires the event, but not tab.

Is there a solution to my goal?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You might also want to fix the if statement (;

Answer (score 15, accepted):

use `onkeydown`. here's a [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/reigel/12z0zbm2/)

```
<input ID="btnClear" onkeydown="return goToFirst();"/>
```

.

```
function goToFirst(evt) {
    var e = event || evt; // for trans-browser compatibility
    var charCode = e.which || e.keyCode;

    alert(charCode);
    if (charCode == 9 ) {
        document.getElementById('txtFirstName').focus();
        document.getElementById('txtFirstName').select();
    }

    return false;
};
```

Comment: `onkeypress` is a combination of `onkeydown` and `onkeyup`. maybe try `onkeyup`, that maybe, you'll know why it didn't work on `onkeypress`.. :)

Comment: onkeyup also worked, wonder why onkeypress doesn't?!... anyway thanks alot man!

Comment: I think "if (charCode = 9 )" should be "if (charCode === 9 )" in your fiddle

Comment: @Reigel is onkeydown still valid? Doesn't work in Chrome.

Comment: var e = event || evt; is not working in my mozilla firefox

Comment: Needs to be updated to remove the line `var e = event || evt; // for trans-browser compatibility` and change `var charCode = e.which || e.keyCode;` to `var charCode = evt.which || evt.keyCode;`

Comment: @JasdeepKhalsa the idea here is to allow browser compatibility in both cases of the browser using 'event' or 'evt'

Answer (score -1):

I solved a similar problem using ev.stopPropagation() and ev.preventDefault() after show the input.

Comment: If you've solved this problem, can the answer give you a clearer explanation?
In the questioner's code, it would be nice to add a code block explaining how and what code was used in some part.